# How Can I execute a function in angr using concrete value?

Tags: reverse-engineering, angr, symbolic-execution

In Angr, I have a code like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>  

typedef struct A_struct
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
} A;


void bar(A* a){
    a->data2 += 1;
}

void foo(A* a)  
{
    a->data1 += 1;
    bar(a);
}

int main()  
{  
    A a;
    a.data1 = 1;
    a.data2 = 2;
    foo(&a);
    printf("%d, %d\n", a.data1, a.data2);
    return 0;  
}
```

I compile the C code into Binary, and I want to use angr to execute function `foo`, how can I just execute the `foo` without executing the `main`?
For Symbolic execution, how can I get the execution trace of structure A?
For Concrete execution, If I set `a` as the memory section, how can I get the result of `a`?

I tried to use BVS as the parameter

```py
import angr
import claripy

b = angr.Project('test_fun')
func_addr = b.loader.find_symbol('foo').rebased_addr
print(func_addr)
f = b.factory.callable(func_addr)
x = claripy.BVS('x', 64)
res = f(x)
print(res, type(res))
```

but the result is not what I want, the result is x_40_64, I don't know what is this. And I don't know how to pass some concrete memory as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for the function `project.factory.call_state`, you can pass arguments to the function by passing positional arguments after the address argument.
after that you can initialize a simulation manager with that state, and simulate it.